# If blood vessels mostly aren't supplied by parasympathetic nerves, how effects through M3-ACh receptors are mediated?

Tags: physiology, pharmacology, neuroanatomy

Blood vessels throughout the body mostly aren't supplied by any parasympathetic fibres. But the effects of ACh through M3-ACh receptors would infact release NO (which acts on VSM and causes vasodilation), which is demonstrated after ACh intravenous administration.

My question is how is it physiologically mediated? (i.e. the ACh mediated vasodilation)

*VSM= vascular smooth muscle
*NO= Nitric Oxide
*Ach= Acetylcholine
*M3 (Muscarinic type 3) Acetylcholine receptor

Comment: ACh=acetylcholine? NO=nitric oxide? M3-ACh? Might be useful to spell out acronyms/abbreviations the first time you use them (I see you have VSM at the bottom), since odds are the average user of this site is not in your field

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the question.